# How to access data from the vision capture cards to opencv?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am trying to get data from an a endoscope into my opencv code in python. The endoscope machine has a dvi output and I have a Datapath vision capture card which helps read it into my system. I understand that opencv can only read from usb cameras or ip webcams. I was wondering if anyone has done this kind of a read into opencv?
Pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you can capture from endoscope with ffmpeg or gstremer?

Comment: I am able to get the stream from the endoscope using the application that came with the card at the moment.

Comment: Windows, Linux?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: This card has a DirectShow interface. OpenCV must be compatible with it. Try to set the DSHOW backend on VideoCapture: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html

Comment: Do you any sample programs accessing the directshow from opencv?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer i found in a forum, if this might be of any help ! I dont know the difference between a dvi - ffmpeg ! check if there is a option to convert your dvi output to ffmpeg.

----------------------Answered below------------------------

I’m attempting to pipe to stdout via ffmpeg so it can be read by OpenCV. It seems like streamlink can pipe directly to stdout. I may mess with that when I have a chance, too.

Finally got it. I was previously saving images to disk then reading them into opencv. That worked, but this solution helps avoid the disk write/read cost for a constant stream of images. What ended up solving it for me was:

Use a named pipe
Piping ffmpeg output to the named pipe
Then reading from that pipe with cv2.VideoCapture
Create the named pipe:

```
if os.path.isfile("/tmp/stream"):
    os.remove("/tmp/stream")
else:
    call(["mkfifo", "/tmp/stream"])
```

ffmpeg call:

```
p = Popen(["ffmpeg -c:v h264 -i pipe:0 -r 1 -f image2pipe - > /tmp/stream"], stdout = PIPE, bufsize=10**8, shell=True)
recordStatus = p.poll()        # check PIPE status every once in a while to make sure it hasn't closed early
```

Read with opencv:

```
path = "/tmp/stream"
raw_image = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
ret, frame = raw_image.read()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I seem to have troubles when I try to input the name of the device as seen in the list of devices using ffpeg from the command line. And as a result the read does not happen. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to have the DVI stream written to a file, FFMPEG/gstreamer read the file stream, and then pipe the input into OpenCV.

Comment: I am able to read the data using ffmpeg and write it to a file, but I want to have a continuous stream of data from the DVI stream into my opencv code.